# From C#, not seeing exposed methods of COM objects

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop, atl

I have Visual Studio 2015. I created a Visual C++ ATL project. I named it WinHookLayer.
Using Wizard I added a class and selected ATL COM+ 1.0 Component and created a class with short name HookWrapper and clicked Finish.

From class view, I added a method named SetMouseHook to HookWrapper.
In HookWrapper.cpp, I see the following code generated: -

```
STDMETHODIMP CHookWrapper::SetMouseHook(LONG threadId, LONG* result)
{
    // TODO: Add your implementation code here
    return S_OK;
}
```

I added my code inside it, made the dll and registered it.
Then I created a C# Windows Forms application. I added reference to WinHookLayer.tlb
and also added using WinHookLayerLib; in the .cs file.

I wrote

```
HookWrapper hkWrapper = new HookWrapper();
```

Till now it works fine.
But SetMouseHook function is not visible from hkWrapper.

I can see the methods "Equals", "GetHashCode", "GetType" and "ToString" but not the method I added.

Comment: SetMouseHook is inside C++ dll. The C++ dll project is an ATL COM+1.0 project. I added SetMouseHook using Add method wizard. I right clicked on IHookWrapper in class view and selected Add Method. There I entered the method name as SetMouseHook.

Comment: There is a .tlb explorer somewhere in the tools (its name escapes me, if I remember will add a comment) - check to see if it includes your method definition

Comment: I checked in object viewer. Do not see the method there.

Comment: You need to add the method to respective IDL interface. This way it is published through TLB and visible on the imports, and on the C++ side your class inherits it and your implementation is picked up.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. In class view of the C++ dll project, I see 3 entries for IHookWrapper. Earlier I was adding the method to some other entry. Don't know why that did not work. But when I added the method to the last entry (the entry just before IHookWrapperVtbl), then it works.